# How to detect when "Done" button pressed when modal view is presented from framework

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, if-statement

If a modal view is presented from a framework (in my case eventkit), What would be the correct way to detect if the cancel or if the done button is pressed.  In my example on the `didCompleteWithaction` my modal view is dismissed, an alert view is fired.  I want the alert view only fired if the `Done` button is pressed rather than the cancel button.

My initial thoughts were an `if` statement when the the done button is pressed, however im not sure how I get the property of the done button.

```
- (void)eventEditViewController:(EKEventEditViewController *)controller
      didCompleteWithAction:(EKEventEditViewAction)action {

// Dismiss the modal view controller
[controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"message" message:@"Added to calender" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

[alert show];


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the delegate's protocol reference: [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/EventKitUI/Reference/EKEventEditViewDelegateRef/Reference/Reference.html)

You will have to check the `action` parameter of the delegate method, as it represents what action the user chose.

Eg

```
- (void)eventEditViewController:(EKEventEditViewController *)controller
      didCompleteWithAction:(EKEventEditViewAction)action {

// Dismiss the modal view controller
[controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

//this checks what action the user chose:
if (action == EKEventEditViewActionSaved) {
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"message" message:@"Added to calender" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

     [alert show];
     }


}
```

I don't know what action will be triggered by the "done" button, possibly ...ActionSaved - but check it out yourself.

Comment: Thanks great answer, checked the docs and got it from your answer before your update - which is correct. Thanks again! (had to delete and re edit comment due to shocking grammar!)

Answer (score 1):

I may be way off, but isn't [`action` parameter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKitUI/Reference/EKEventEditViewDelegateRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/EKEventEditViewAction) what you want?

> #### EKEventEditViewAction
>
> Describes the action the user took to end editing.

```
typedef enum {
   EKEventEditViewActionCanceled,
   EKEventEditViewActionSaved,
   EKEventEditViewActionDeleted
} EKEventEditViewAction;
```

I suppose `EKEventEditViewActionSaved` should correspond to Done button.

Comment: `EKEventEditViewActionSaved` yes it does thanks for your answer plus 1